# Matplotlib barplot linewidth not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Setting the edgecolor and width on a barplot results in only a single bar having a line around it:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
print(mpl.__version__)
2.1.0

mpl.pyplot.barh(y=[1, 2, 3], 
        width=[1, 2, 3],
        linewidth=2,
        edgecolor='k');
```

[image]

Adding an alpha parameter seems to correct the issue:

```
mpl.pyplot.barh(y=[1, 2, 3], 
        width=[1, 2, 3],
        linewidth=2,
        edgecolor='k',
        alpha=1);
```

[image]

This seems like a bug, though perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, [it is a bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9351).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I spent a bit of time searching both the matplotlib issue tracker and SO, but should have spent more!

Comment: Note: As a workaround, you can do `hbar(y, width, linewidth=2, edgecolor=['k']*len(y))`.

Comment: Nice. @johnchase you may also add your workaround using `alpha=1` to the duplicate, such that all possible answers are in one place.